# Format generated by admin-import 'AF4.3.0' is no longer supported

Tags: neo4j

### Overall Problem

I imported data with the admin-import tool, and now am unable to start neo4j because of a an error which appears to be related to the output format from the input tool. Can I do anything to salvage the database and get neo4j running? Or will I need to modify the import command and redo the whole thing? It takes quite some time to import, so being able to use the existing import is preferred if at all possible.

### Import

I imported a large amount of data (~10TB after imported into the database). With the neo4j admin import command below. (I've changed the exact types/filenames but this is otherwise the exact same command)

```
../bin/neo4j-admin database import full  \
     --nodes=Nodetype1=nodeset1.csv \
     --nodes=Nodetype2=nodeset2.csv \
     --nodes=Nodetype3=nodeset3.csv \
     --nodes=Nodetype4=nodeset4.csv \
     --relationships=Rtype1=relations1.csv \
     --relationships=Rtype2=relations2.csv \
     --relationships=Rtype3=relations3.csv \
     --relationships=Rtype4=relations4.csv \
     --relationships=Rtype5=relations5.csv \
     --multiline-fields=false \
     --trim-strings=false \
     --skip-duplicate-nodes=true \
     --skip-bad-relationships=true \
     --overwrite-destination=true \
     --format=high_limit \
     neo4j
```

### Error When Starting Neo4j

This process completed successfully, however when I try to start neo4j I get a number of errors. With the root cause appearing to be this one

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UnableToMigrateException: The selected target store format 'AF4.3.0' (introduced in 4.3.0) is no longer supported
```

I am running the neo4j:enterprise docker image. (I believe version neo4j enterprise version 5.1)

The full log is posted below

```
Changed password for user 'neo4j'. IMPORTANT: this change will only take effect if performed before the database is started for the first time.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.517+0000 INFO  The license agreement was accepted with environment variable NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes when the Software was started.

The license agreement is available https://neo4j.com/terms/licensing/

If you do not have a commercial license and want to evaluate the Software
please read the terms of the evaluation agreement before you accept.
https://neo4j.com/terms/enterprise_us/

(c) Neo4j Sweden AB. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this Software without a proper commercial license, or evaluation license
with Neo4j,Inc. or its affiliates is prohibited.
Neo4j has the right to terminate your usage if you are not compliant.

Email inquiries can be directed to: licensing@neo4j.com

More information is also available at: https://neo4j.com/licensing/

2022-11-03 16:43:54.520+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'causal_clustering.transaction_advertised_address'. It is replaced by 'server.cluster.advertised_address'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.521+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'causal_clustering.raft_advertised_address'. It is replaced by 'server.cluster.raft.advertised_address'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.521+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'causal_clustering.discovery_advertised_address'. It is replaced by 'server.discovery.advertised_address'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.521+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'dbms.directories.data'. It is replaced by 'server.directories.data'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.521+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'dbms.directories.logs'. It is replaced by 'server.directories.logs'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.521+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy'. It is replaced by 'db.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.522+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'dbms.default_listen_address'. It is replaced by 'server.default_listen_address'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.522+0000 WARN  Use of deprecated setting 'dbms.memory.pagecache.size'. It is replaced by 'server.memory.pagecache.size'.
2022-11-03 16:43:54.523+0000 INFO  Starting...
2022-11-03 16:43:55.653+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 5.1.0 ========
2022-11-03 16:43:55.673+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{1d0ed675} (1d0ed675-d5db-4cc0-bc00-e655ffac7ebe)
2022-11-03 16:43:59.798+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on 0.0.0.0:7474.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /data/databases
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:255) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:193) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseDBMSProvider.createManagementService(EnterpriseDBMSProvider.java:36) ~[neo4j-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseDBMSProvider.<init>(EnterpriseDBMSProvider.java:28) ~[neo4j-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseDBMSFactory.createManagementService(EnterpriseDBMSFactory.java:18) ~[neo4j-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseBootstrapper.createNeo(EnterpriseBootstrapper.java:21) ~[neo4j-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:164) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:85) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:19) ~[neo4j-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconcilerModule@47c15468' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The selected target store format 'AF4.3.0' (introduced in 4.3.0) is no longer supported".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:370) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:246) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementException: A triggered DbmsReconciler job failed with the following cause
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerResult.join(ReconcilerResult.java:50) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.StartupOperator.startSystem(StartupOperator.java:52) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.TopologyGraphOperators.startSystem(TopologyGraphOperators.java:70) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconcilerModule.startInitialDatabases(DbmsReconcilerModule.java:111) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconcilerModule.start(DbmsReconcilerModule.java:99) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:353) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:246) ~[neo4j-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementException: Unable to start database `DatabaseId{00000000[system]}`
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.unableToStartDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:202) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:181) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.forSingleDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:242) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:140) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransitionAction(Transition.java:94) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransition(Transition.java:83) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:257) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionSteps(DbmsReconciler.java:245) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.executeJob(DbmsReconciler.java:203) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.lambda$scheduleReconciliationJob$2(DbmsReconciler.java:187) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJob.executeJob(ReconcilerJob.java:49) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJobManager$ReconciliationWorker.run(ReconcilerJobManager.java:192) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$asCallable$1(ThreadPool.java:136) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$submit$0(ThreadPool.java:108) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database@10eaa4d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The selected target store format 'AF4.3.0' (introduced in 4.3.0) is no longer supported".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:370) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.EnterpriseDatabase.start(EnterpriseDatabase.java:47) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:179) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.forSingleDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:242) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:140) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransitionAction(Transition.java:94) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransition(Transition.java:83) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:257) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionSteps(DbmsReconciler.java:245) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.executeJob(DbmsReconciler.java:203) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.lambda$scheduleReconciliationJob$2(DbmsReconciler.java:187) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJob.executeJob(ReconcilerJob.java:49) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJobManager$ReconciliationWorker.run(ReconcilerJobManager.java:192) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$asCallable$1(ThreadPool.java:136) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$submit$0(ThreadPool.java:108) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UnableToMigrateException: The selected target store format 'AF4.3.0' (introduced in 4.3.0) is no longer supported
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.AbstractDatabase.handleStartupFailure(AbstractDatabase.java:211) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.AbstractDatabase.start(AbstractDatabase.java:164) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:353) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.EnterpriseDatabase.start(EnterpriseDatabase.java:47) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:179) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.forSingleDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:242) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:140) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransitionAction(Transition.java:94) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransition(Transition.java:83) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:257) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionSteps(DbmsReconciler.java:245) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.executeJob(DbmsReconciler.java:203) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.lambda$scheduleReconciliationJob$2(DbmsReconciler.java:187) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJob.executeJob(ReconcilerJob.java:49) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJobManager$ReconciliationWorker.run(ReconcilerJobManager.java:192) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$asCallable$1(ThreadPool.java:136) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$submit$0(ThreadPool.java:108) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UnableToMigrateException: The selected target store format 'AF4.3.0' (introduced in 4.3.0) is no longer supported
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.doUpgradeCheck(StoreMigrator.java:326) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.upgradeIfNeeded(StoreMigrator.java:195) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.upgradeStore(Database.java:731) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.Database.specificStart(Database.java:383) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.database.AbstractDatabase.start(AbstractDatabase.java:156) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:353) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.EnterpriseDatabase.start(EnterpriseDatabase.java:47) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:179) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.forSingleDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:242) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.database.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:140) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransitionAction(Transition.java:94) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.Transition$Prepared.doTransition(Transition.java:83) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:257) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionStep(DbmsReconciler.java:258) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.doTransitionSteps(DbmsReconciler.java:245) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.executeJob(DbmsReconciler.java:203) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.DbmsReconciler.lambda$scheduleReconciliationJob$2(DbmsReconciler.java:187) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJob.executeJob(ReconcilerJob.java:49) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at com.neo4j.dbms.ReconcilerJobManager$ReconciliationWorker.run(ReconcilerJobManager.java:192) ~[neo4j-dbms-enterprise-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$asCallable$1(ThreadPool.java:136) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.scheduler.ThreadPool.lambda$submit$0(ThreadPool.java:108) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
2022-11-03 16:43:59.801+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2022-11-03 16:43:59.801+0000 INFO  Stopped.
```

Comment: Same here. I tried upgrading from 4.3 to 4.4 by performing a neo4j-admin backup and restore (both from a neo4j-enterprise 4.4 installation) with dbms.allow_upgrade=true enabled. However, neo4j never seems to upgrade the store format from 4.3 to 4.4. I'm stuck :-(